# Android Face Detection apis provide face rectangle in different coordinate system in different phones

Tags: android, face-detection

I found that in android face detection api, the obtained rectangle from `onFaceDetection` callback follows different coordinates in different android phones. According to android documents, the origin of the coordinates for face rectangle is at center of the screen. But in some phones I found the origin point (0,0) lies at top - right corner of the screen in portrait mode.

My prediction is, it is manufacturer dependent. I tested for samsung and micromax, it works fine according to android document whereas for sony xperia M and L, it follows coordinates originating from top-right corner.

My question is, can I identify that the rectangle obtained in `onFaceDetection` callback follows which coordinate system?